# In RequireJs, how do I instruct the optimizer to to produce hash output files names?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I run the optimizer like this

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/node /tmp/r.j/r.js -o name=main out=test.js baseUrl=.
```

for test
Now, how do I tell the optimizer to output the filename as a hash of the content (obviously to set max expires) and then rename the dependency in the relevant require calls?

An example situation will be something like this

```
require({
        baseUrl: '{{ STATIC_URL }}js',
        paths: {
            jquery: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min',
            jqueryui: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min'
        }
    }, ['order!jquery','order!jqueryui','order!main']);
```

requirejs should be pulling something like 13KUJAW78M.js

Based on [Miller Medeiros’s suggestion](http://groups.google.com/group/requirejs/browse_thread/thread/7667702b7aaa7f83) I am planning to put all the require calls into a single master file. This will also mean that all such calls will also need to be optimized.

e.g

```
switch(document.location.pathName){
        case '/foo':
            require(['sections/foo/main']);
            break;
        case '/foo/bar':
            require(['sections/foo/main', 'core/bar']);
            break;
        default:
            require('sections/home');
    }
```

> require(['sections/foo/main']);

should be optimized to a hash file.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

RequireJS optimizer doesn't have this option, but you could rename the files and use the [paths config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config) to set alias to the renamed files, see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/requirejs/browse_thread/thread/c0e4806b6e5deb16) for more info.

On your example for instance, if you rename the files to: 'sections/foo/main.123QWERT.js', 'sections/home.4567ASDFG.js', 'core/bar.0284ZXCV.js' you could just add a paths config like this:

```
require.config({
  paths : {
    //alias to new files without JS extension
    'core/bar': 'core/bar.0284ZXCV',
    'sections/home' : 'sections/home.4567ASDFG',
    'sections/foo/main' : 'sections/foo/main.123QWERT'
  }
});
```

The paths config should be on a file that won't be cached, maybe just keep the config on the HTML.

Comment: Will the optimizer add the hash or will i have to do some scripting + regex magic to replace the file names?

Comment: Also can main be compressed along with the other files or should it be separate

Comment: RequireJS optimizer wont add the hash, you will need to generate it manually (or using some tool which I'm not aware off) and pass the paths config so when a modules requires "core/bar" it will load the file "core/bar.HASH_VALUE.js" instead. Depending on your setup you shouldn't need to generate hashes for that many files.

main can be compressed together with the other files.